# Can we create application shortcut with user specified image file (typically SD Card) as ICON

Tags: android

I am able to create application shortcut using below method.

```
  public static void CreateShortCut(Context context, String ShortCutName){
            Intent shortcutintent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
            shortcutintent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
            shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, ShortCutName);

        /*    Parcelable icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context.getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.iconfromresource);  */ //  This work great 
            Parcelable icon =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/myownappicon.png");   /* This doesnt work, Doesnt show any error either.... it just gives Android Default icon instead of  my own myownappicon.png */
            shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon); 
            shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(context.getApplicationContext() , DynamicSplashScreen.class));
            context.sendBroadcast(shortcutintent);
      }
```

Now my question is ,   Can we create Application short cut with user specified Icon file  from SD Card?  Is it doable?

I have tried with  Bitmapfactory with decodefile, unfortunately it didn't work.  If this is doable , let me know where i am going wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Able to Find the solution for my own problem...BitmapFactory.decodeFile will do the trick.

```
 public static void CreateShortCut(Context context, String ShortCutName, String ImageFileName){

            Intent shortcutintent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
            shortcutintent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
            shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, ShortCutName);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImageFileName);   
            Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 72, 72, true);
            shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, scaledBitmap);
            shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(context.getApplicationContext() , SplashScreen.class));
            context.sendBroadcast(shortcutintent);


      }
```

Thanks.